# DataTables for ASP.NET Websites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, datatables

I have a website in C# using Razor for WebPages, and have found the WebGrid to be a bit of a pain to work with since I am trying to edit quantities in rows. I found this:

http://www.datatables.net/index

But all the samples are in PHP. Can this work in C#? Have you used this/would you recommend this?

Comment: This is a JQuery tools. Of course you can use Jquery with C#.
I never use "Datatables", but I'm sure you can. You just need to use the .NET way to support AJAX.

Comment: Thanks @MartinLabelle and everyone else who has provided answers. :-)

Comment: Heres a working sample code  refer -http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2013/07/jquery-datatables-editable-in-aspnet-c.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataTables` is mainly javascript/jquery and works with most any server-side language, including `ASP.net`:

http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/asp_net

Remember server side objects like datagrids, gridviews, datalists, etc simply translate into html tables when your page is displayed in the browser.  `DataTables` simply allows you to take the handle (the id) of the table and translate it to a `datatable` with simple jquery.

From the example on the site:

`$('#example').dataTable();`

Assumes a table with the id `example`.

Comment: I spent over half an hour on that site looking for an ASP.NET reference... I guess I should get more sleep. Thank you @JonH.

Answer (score 1):

DataTables is a javascript based client side grid. It could work with absolutely any server side technology as long as you are providing the output in the expected format.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a jQuery extension and has nothing to do with PHP.

You can use the DataTable with any HTML table, no matter the technology you use on your webserver (be it .NET or PHP, ...). The DataTable allows your users to do some fancy stuff with the data: sorting, filtering, etc on the client machine. But it does not include editing capabilities and while there is an [Editor](http://editor.datatables.net/) plugin that does just that, it comes at a pretty steep price: *$550 for 5 developers*. (there is a free trial)

Answer (score 1):

DataTables works most excellently with ASP.NET. We generally use it combined with ASMX web service calls to populate grids, either with `List<SomeObject>` or a `DataTable` (but there is no way to natively turn a DataTable (.NET type) into JSON (for a WS response), so if that's the route you want to take, you'll need to write a wrapper